# Argument 'fn' is not a function got string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a part in my angular application on which I've binded a controller,
since then I got the Argument 'fn' is not a function Error, can anyone look at my code and explain why I got that Error?

I would be very gratefull :)

html-markup:

```html
<section class="col-lg-12" data-ng-controller="MessageController">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{{ 'MESSAGES' | translate }}</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="margin-left-15">
    <ul class="list-style-button">
      <li data-ng-repeat="message in MSG">{{ message }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

controller:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var controllers = angular.module('portal.controllers');

  controllers.controller('MessageController', ['$scope', 'MessageService', '$rootScope', function MessageController($scope, MessageService, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.MSG = MessageService.getMessages();

    $rootScope.$watch('MSG', function(newValue) {
      $scope.MSG = newValue;
    });
  }]);
}());
```

Service:

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var messageServices = angular.module('portal.services');

  messageServices.factory('MessageService', ['MessageData', 'localStorageService', 'UserService'], function(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService) {
    return new MessageService(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService);
  });

  function MessageService(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService) {
    this.messageData = MessageData;
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
    this.userService = UserService;
  }

  MessageService.prototype.getMessages = function() {
    var locale = this.userService.getUserinfoLocale();
    var messages = this.localStorageService.get(Constants.key_messages + locale);
    if (messages !== null && messages !== undefined) {
      return JSON.parse(messages);
    } else {
      return this.messageData.query({
        locale: locale
      }, $.proxy(function(data, locale) {
        this.save(Constants.key_messages + locale, JSON.stringify(data));
      }, this));
    }
  };

  MessageService.prototype.save = function(key, value) {
    this.localStorageService.add(key, value);
  };

}());
```

data:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var data = angular.module('portal.data');

  data.factory('MessageData', function($resource) {
    return $resource(Constants.url_messages, {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          locale: 'locale'
        },
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  });
}());
```

order of js files in html head:

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-localstorage.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/portal.js"></script>
```

Comment: possibly something to do with jQuery, as in when you are adding a plugin to jQuery with `$.fn.extend({...`. maybe you haven't include jQuery lib

Comment: jQuery is the first script that's added in my head tags, I'll edit the question with the order of the js files

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The problem was in using the 'wrong' syntax to create the service 
instead of using:

```
messageServices.factory('MessageService', 
    ['MessageData','localStorageService', 'UserService'], 
    function(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService){
        return new MessageService(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService);
    }
);
```

I had to use:

```
messageServices.factory('MessageService', 
    ['MessageData','localStorageService', 'UserService', 
    function(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService){
        return new MessageService(MessageData, localStorageService, UserService);
    }
]);
```

I closed the array with parameters to soon, and since I'm still learning I didn't see it directly, anyhow I hope I can help others who stumble upon this.

Comment: This is really nasty. In my case, I mistakenly put one service outside the square bracket (so all the parenthesis and brackets are matched well), and it took me long long time to figure it out because I refactored a lot of codes. So, again, you get this same meaningless error message when you have something like: `app.factory('x', 'y', ['z', function(y, z) {...}]);` (notice y is outside of square bracket). The worst of all, it doesn't tell you which file has this problem. so if you have changed a lot of files, go figure.

Comment: or
```config('someFactory', 'otherFactory', superFunction)```
instead
```config(['someFactory', 'otherFactory', superFunction])```

Comment: In my case removing dependency names in square brackets helped. Like so `.factory('historyentries', function($http){}` instead of `.factory('historyentries', ['$http'],  function($http)`

Comment: Those lines no needed, if you removed it then it's automatically works `'MessageData','localStorageService', 'UserService'],`

Answer (score 9):

Today I got the same kind of error doing that silly mistake:

```
(function(){

  angular
    .module('mymodule')
    .factory('myFactory', 'myFactory');   // <-- silly mistake 

  myFactory.$inject = ['myDeps'];
  function myFactory(myDeps){
    ...
  }

}());
```

instead of that:

```
(function(){

  angular
    .module('mymodule')
    .factory('myFactory', myFactory);   // <-- right way to write it    

  myFactory.$inject = ['myDeps'];
  function myFactory(myDeps){
    ...
  }

}());
```

In fact the string "myFactory" was brought into the injector who was waiting for a function and not a string. 
That explained the [ng:areq] error.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers helped me considerably in correcting the same issue I had in my application that arose from a different cause.

At built time, my client app is being concatenated and minified, so I'm writing my Angular specifically to avoid related issues. I define my `config` as follows

```
config.$inject = [];
function config() {
    // config stuff
}
```

(I define a function, `$inject` it as a module and declare what it is).

And then I tried to register the `config` just as I registered other modules in my app (controllers, directives, etc..).

```
angular.module("app").config('config', config); // this is bad!

// for example, this is right
angular.module("app").factory('mainService', mainService);
```

This is wrong, and gave me the aforementioned error. So I changed to

```
angular.module("app").config(config);
```

And it worked.
I guess the angular devs intended `config` to have a singular instance and by so having Angular not accept a name when `config` is registered.

Comment: It is the same for the Run method! Thank you very much for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and In my case the problem was with angular-cookies.js file. It was in folder with other angularjs scripts and when I have used gulp to minify my js files the error occured.

Simple solution was just to place the angular-cookies.js file to another folder, outside the selected folder to minify js files.

Answer (score 0):

My case

```
  let app: any = angular.module("ngCartosServiceWorker"),
    requires: any[] = [
      "$log",
      "$q",
      "$rootScope",
      "$window",
      "ngCartosServiceWorker.registration",
      PushNotification
    ];
  app.service("ngCartosServiceWorker.PushNotification");
```

I forgot to add requires Array as parameters to service like this

```
app.service("ngCartosServiceWorker.PushNotification", requires);
```