# AngularJS SPA is not working in Web Api project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I have created a web api project and after that i am going to create single page application but getting some error so i am posting my code below:

My angularjs code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config('$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'tpl/users.html',
        controller: 'myController'
    })
    .when('/addusers',  {
        templateUrl: 'tpl/addusers.html',
        controller: 'addusers'
    })
    .when('/admin',{
        templateUrl: 'tpl/admin.html',
        controller: 'admin'
    });
});

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Home';
});

app.controller('admin', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Admin';
});

app.controller('addusers', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'addusers';
});
```

and my html page:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="#/admin">Admin</a>
    <a href="#/addusers">Add Users</a>
    <br />
    <div ng-view> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and getting below angularjs error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0AD%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0ADb%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A106%0AWa%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A193%0Asc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A423%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A398%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A386%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Agc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309%0Afc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170%0Afc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387%0AXc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A214%3A469%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A145%3A67%0Aoe%2Fc%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A223%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Aoe%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A207%0AEventListener.handleEvent*sb%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A143%3A241%0Aa%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A150%3A402%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A149%3A381%0AS.prototype%5Bc%5D%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A154%3A57%0AS.prototype.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A145%3A122%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A214%3A447%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A2%0A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller definitions (dependency injection parts) is wrong.
You can follow the [john papa's style guide for angular](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'tpl/users.html',
        controller: 'myController'
    }).when('/addusers',  {
        templateUrl: 'tpl/addusers.html',
        controller: 'addusers'
    }).when('/admin',{
        templateUrl: 'tpl/admin.html',
        controller: 'admin'
    });
}]);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Home';
}]);

app.controller('admin', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Admin';
}]);

app.controller('addusers', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'addusers';
}]);
```

Comment: @scokmen, my bad, I inadvertently down voted this :(  I'll up vote it when SO lets me.  Sorry bout that.

Comment: @scokmen, it looks like you have to make an edit before I can up vote it.  Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a SPA in angular as well and got the same error very recently,

This is something that i found to happen when i was using ngRoute. ngRoute works but it seems very messy to me and kept giving me this error and some other ones.

I was probably just using it wrong, but i recommend you switch to "[UI-Router](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv-4ii9KfOAhXI5IMKHWU8CO4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fangular-ui%2Fui-router&usg=AFQjCNGGenLMwsnWDz8t-pkIQlSLFjSb1A&bvm=bv.128617741,bs.1,d.eWE)"

It should clean up the way you do routing and make it easier to handle objects throughout your project.

Comment: Thanks Richard Sussan  i will use it in future but what's wrong with my code. i have matched it with many examples but not getting anything wrong and getting same error

Comment: So through that link the error says "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string".    I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095129/argument-fn-is-not-a-function-got-string), which addresses that issue. This is probably an error in some other bit of code that you have not given in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the config wrong.  You don't need to use '$routeProvider' as a parameter.

Incorrect

```
app.config('$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
});
```

Correct

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
});
```

Also, Angular no longer uses ngRoute out of the box. It's a separate file you need to include (note the version):

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js