# Angular JS Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: sessionService <- sessionService

Tags: html, angularjs

I initially was getting the error `Argument 'fn' is not a function got string` after some investigation and following [Argument 'fn' is not a function got string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095129/argument-fn-is-not-a-function-got-string) I stumbled upon **Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: sessionService <- sessionService**.

The version of AngularJS I am using is 1.6.6. Thank you for the help!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Services and Factories</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body ng-controller="sessionController as vm">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Services and Factories</h1>

    <div class="form-group-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.model.name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Nick Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.model.nickname">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.setServiceSession()" value="Save with Service">

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.getServiceSession()" value="Retrieve from Service">


            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.clearServiceSession()" value="Clear from Service">

        </div>
    </div>
<pre>{{vm.model | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/sessionService.js"></script>
<script src="app/sessionController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
```

sessionController.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('sessionController',['sessionService',

    function (sessionService) {

    var vm = this;


    function sessionController(sessionService) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.getServiceSession = function () {

            vm.model = {
                name: sessionService.get('name'),
                nickname: sessionService.get('nickname'),
                status: 'Retrieved by service on ' + new Date()
            }
        };

        vm.setServiceSession = function () {

            sessionService.save('name', vm.model.name);
            sessionService.save('nickname', vm.model.nickname);
            vm.getServiceSession();
        };

        vm.clearServiceSession = function () {

            sessionService.clear();
            vm.getServiceSession();
        }

    }
}

]);
```

sessionService.js

```
angular.module('app').service('sessionService',['$window','sessionService',
function sessionService($window) {

    this.save = save;
    this.get = get;
    this.clear = clear;

    function save(key, value) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);

    }

    function get(key) {
        return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }

    function clear() {
        $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Why are you injecting `sessionService` into `sessionService`? I think you might just want to remove the `'sessionService',` from sessionService.js

Comment: @ExplosionPills thank you I dont see the error But the functionality of buttons is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In sessionService.js:

You are telling Angular to register (create) a service called `sessionService` that has two dependencies - `$window` and `sessionService`. This is the circular dependency as the `sessionService` can't depend on itself.

To avoid the circular dependency, you need to remove `'sessionService'` from the dependency list.

```
angular.module('app').service('sessionService',['$window', 
function sessionService($window) {

    this.save = save;
    this.get = get;
    this.clear = clear;

    function save(key, value) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);

    }

    function get(key) {
        return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }

    function clear() {
        $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }
}]);
```

I think you've done this by mistake, but it may help to read the documentation on Angular services:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#dependencies

Comment: thankyou for the detailed answer and making me understand